# A* algorithm with Manhattan heuristic

Tags: java, algorithm

I am implementing the NXN puzzel in 2-dimensional array (using Java).

My questions are:

1)
How do I calculate the Manhattan distance in 2-Dimensional array

2)
how do I generate the successors (neighbours) of a node (current node) in 2-dimensional array.

I have seen on the internet many examples how they do them in 1-dimensional array but now I need them in 2-dimensional array.

### Edit

How do I move a tile UP, DOWN, LEFT or RIGHT in Java? and what are the things I must check?  Need some explanation on how to generate the successors by moving UP, DOWN, LEFT or RIGHT in 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 4):

1. Distance from point (a,b) to (c,d) = Math.abs(a-c) + Math.abs(b-d)
2. Look at something called `floodfill`. It's basically like this:

   ```
   public void floodfill(x,y, distanceSoFar)
   {
       if (x is out of bounds || y is out of bounds)
           return
       if ((x,y) == destination))
       {
           distance = distanceSoFar;
           return;
       }

       floodfill(x+1,y,distanceSoFar + 1);
       floodfill(x-1,y,distanceSoFar + 1);
       floodfill(x,y+1,distanceSoFar + 1);
       floodfill(x,y-1,distanceSoFar + 1);
   }
   ```

Then call `floodfill(x,y,0)` where x and y is your starting point. The distance to your destination will be stored in the global variable distance. (Didn't really use a* though...)

Comment: oops I don't know why the code formatting messed up... I'm new sorry.

Comment: no problem. I really want to use the A* to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

1. The [Manhattan distance](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/manhattanDistance.html) is just |x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>| + |y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>|
2. The successors of a node are generated by all the legal moves of your game from the current node. How this is done depends on the rules of the game, not just on the game being played on a 2D board.

**EDIT**

Here's one way of generating a list of adjacent points on a 2D array:

```
ArrayList<Point> adjacentPoints(Point point) {
    // W and H are class fields indicating width/height of 2D array
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    if (point.x > 0) {
        points.add(new Point(point.x - 1, point.y);
    }
    if (point.y > 0) {
        points.add(new Point(point.x - 1, point.y);
    }
    if (point.x < W - 1) {
        points.add(new Point(point.x + 1, point.y);
    }
    if (point.y < H - 1) {
        points.add(new Point(point.x, point.y + 1);
    }
    return points;
}
```

This could, of course, be improved in terms of efficiency, but it does the job.

Comment: I have to generate the successors based of the  f = g + h. g = distance from starting node to the current node, h = manhattan hereustic(1 stepcost).

Comment: @EddyFreeman - Generating successors has nothing to do with heuristic search. The formula `f = g + h` enters into selecting which successor to explore next. If you can move from any point in the array to any 4-adjacent point (left, right, up, down; no diagonal moves), then just try each one and eliminate those with out-of-bounds coordinates.

Comment: Good Ted. This is what am looking for. I think my question was not formulated well. How do i implement it in Java by moving to the four adjacent points. Can you please help me by explaining it well to me or point me to any source i can have more information. thanks

Comment: @EddyFreeman - Glad to help. Note that if the rules allow wrapping around the board (moving right from the right edge brings you to the left edge), then the logic would just be changed to use modular arithmetic instead of `if` testing. You'd then always have 4 successor nodes.